# store form values in URL params

Tags: jquery

I have a d3 chart with some `<input>` elements for configuration. I'd like these configuration options to update URL params as they're changed, and obviously when the page is loaded these URL params should be used as default values.

This seems like a basic piece of functionality on a lot of sites, is there a jQuery library out there (I couldn't find one) that I could just drop in? Or do I need to roll my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cheack Ben Allmans jQuery BBQ, http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Or you can roll your own for simple cases by just watching hashchange event and storing things up in hash tag.

> jQuery BBQ leverages the HTML5 hashchange event to allow simple, yet
>   powerful bookmarkable #hash history. In addition, jQuery BBQ provides
>   a full .deparam() method, along with both hash state management, and
>   fragment / query string parse and merge utility methods.